# Palindrome checking with an array

Tags: c++, arrays, assembly, masm, masm32

I'm stuck on how to check for a palindrome using MASM.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include<string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

extern "C"
char test(char*, int);


int main()
{
char arr[] = {NULL};


cout << "Enter a string: " << endl;
cin >> arr;



int name = strlen(arr);
test(arr, name);
if (name == 1)
{
    cout << "It is a palindrome! " << endl;

}
else
    cout << "Not a palindrome. " << endl;

return 0;
  }
```

I asked the user for a string and insert it to an array. I send it to the assembly file and it would return a '1' if its true or '0' if false.

```
.686
.model flat

.code


_test PROC ;named _test because C automatically prepends an underscode, it is needed to interoperate
push ebp
mov ebp,esp ;stack pointer to ebp

mov eax,[ebp+8]
mov ecx,[ebp+12]
mov ebp,0
mov edi,0
mov edx,0



loopMe: 
cmp ebp,ecx
je True

mov al,[eax+edi]
mov bl,[edx+esi]
cmp al,bl   ;compare 
jne false   ;if not equal then jump to false
inc edi     
dec esi
jmp loopMe

True:
mov eax,1
jmp allDone

False:
mov eax,0
jmp allDone


allDone:    
pop ebp
ret
_test ENDP

END
```

when I enter a string it seems to always return 0. I checked the debugger and it would always jump to the False label even though the values are equal. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _`cin >> arr;`_ Is undefined behavior.

Comment: Why not write the code fully in C++, and then use something like [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) to determine what the assembly code will look like?  You know the generated assembly would be correct, since the C++ program would be correct. Then if necessary, adjust the assembly code produced.

Answer (score 0):

You are in C++ use string.

replace

```
char arr[] = {NULL}; // by the way NULL here has no sence.
```

by

```
std::string arr;
```

And use method of string to do what you want:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/

Comment: That won't help much regarding the assembly part.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's help for the c++ part. I let other answer for asm part.

Answer (score -1):

so I ended up changing the code a bit and got it to work.

```
int main()
{
char arr[32] = {NULL};


cout << "Enter a string: " << endl;
cin >> arr;



int name = strlen(arr);
int palindrome= test(arr, name);

if (palindrome )
{
    cout << "It is a palindrome! " << endl;

}
else
    cout << "Not a palindrome. " << endl;

return 0;
}
```

then for the asm file

```
.686
.model flat

.code


_test PROC ;named _test because C automatically prepends an underscode, it   is needed to interoperate
push ebp
mov ebp,esp ;stack pointer to ebp

mov ebx,[ebp+8]
mov ecx,[ebp+12]
mov edx,ebx
add edx,ecx
dec edx




loopMe: 
cmp ebx,edx
jge True

mov ch,[ebx]
mov cl,[edx]
cmp ch,cl   ;compare 
jne false   ;if not equal then jump to false
inc ebx     
dec edx
jmp loopMe

True:
mov eax,1
jmp allDone

False:
mov eax,0
jmp allDone


allDone:    
pop ebp
ret
_test ENDP

 END
```

My only problem now is if I input Mom instead of mom it would say that its not a palindrome. I just need to figure out how to ignore cases in assembly.

Comment: Convert all alphabetic characters to lowercase.  If they're in the uppercase range, OR with `0x20`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: or ch,32 and or cl,32 did it for me.

Comment: note that that makes `@` into `\`` (back-quote), and `[` into `{`, and so on, for non alphabetic characters.  (http://www.asciitable.com/).  This is why I suggested doing it conditionally, in case you care about non-alphabetic characters.  (Interestingly, the digits 0-9 and `' '` (space) all have that bit set already, so they're unmodified.  So OR with 0x20 works in more non-alphabetic cases than AND with `~0x20`)